# The probability of success of a event is 32% find its failure %.

Tags: probability

The probability of success of a event is $32\%$ find its failure $\%$.

> **My Answer**
>
> Probability of success = $32\%$
>
> Probability of failure = $(100 - 32)\% = 68\%$
>
> So, $P(E) = 68\%$.

Is it correct, teacher crossed and marked it as incorrect?

Comment: Looks fine to me, but if your teacher marked it as incorrect, there are several possible reasons for it. Maybe you misunderstood the question, or maybe you didn't justify your result well enough. We can't really judge this on the site, you'll have to talk to the teacher about it.

Comment: Yes it looks correct to me too. There must be some other condition(s) must be given in the question if it is incorrect. What was the exact question which was asked?

Comment: This is exact same question.

Comment: The teacher is not infallible either. He / she might just have glanced over it and read wrong. I would ask the teacher, that's the only way you will get an answer. If they were wrong they will (hopefully) admit it and mark it as correct; if you were missing something, they will probably tell you and you will be wiser for it.